# Create weak selectors/functions in swift

Tags: swift, binding, selector, rx-swift

I'm using `RxSwift` in a project and I found that when I bind directly to a selector it captures a strong reference from self and `deinit` wasn't called.

I was wondering how to make selector/func to deal with only a `weak` reference of self.

```swift
viewModel.title
  .drive(onNext: updateTitle)
  .disposed(by: disposeBag)

func updateTitle(_ title: String) {
  navigationItem.title = title
}
```

What I've tried is

```swift
func updateTitle(_ title: String) {
  weak var weakSelf = self
  weakSelf?.navigationItem.title = title
}
```

But still `deinit` is not getting called.

---

Of course one solution would be to remove the `function` entirely

```swift
viewModel.title
  .drive(onNext: { [weak self] title in 
    self?.updateTitle(title)
  )
  .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

but I don't to lose the concise binding code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some looking, apparently you can't make a func weak because it is not saved in the memory, on the other hand closures capture the environment around it.

So my solution was to create a closure as a var:

```swift
viewModel.title
  .drive(onNext: updateTitle)
  .disposed(by: disposeBag)

lazy var updateTitle: ((String) -> Void)? = { [weak self] _ in
  self?.navigationItem.title = $0
}
```

It is a solution but still curious if we can make the selector captures weak reference.

Answer (score 1):

Playing around with it, I found that you can get a syntax like:

```
viewModel.title
  .drive(onNext: weakCapture(self, method: YourViewController.updateTitle))
  .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

The medicine is worse than the disease, but it's a bit of fun. Here's the definition of the helper method:

```
func weakCapture<T: AnyObject, A1>(
    _ target: T,
    method: @escaping (T) -> (A1) -> Void
) -> (A1) -> Void {
    return { [weak target] arg in
        guard let strongTarget = target else { return }
        method(strongTarget)(arg)
    }
}
```

Here's an example usage:

```
var c: C? = C()
let weaklyCapturedFooMethod = weakCapture(c!, method: C.foo)

weaklyCapturedFooMethod(123) // Runs foo(i: 123)
print(c as Any)
c = nil

weaklyCapturedFooMethod(123) // does nothing
```

It's not very nice. :P

I would recommend just using: `{ [weak self] self?.updateTitle($0) }`

Comment: This is a really good idea, but yea, you’re right. The medicine is worse :D
I think my solution was balanced though